# Exchange 2010 OWA HTTPS port

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-web-app

Im trying to access OWA on a different port than 443 for external connections because that port is already assigned to a web server. So Ive set up the router to redirect 445 to 443 internally.

I've appended the external url with port 445 for OWA under `Server Configuration/Client Access/Outlook Web App` so now it looks like `https://mail.itmanx.com:445/owa`, but when I try to access it, it redirects to a login url without the new port number and thus I just end up on the website.

You can see the results by viewing the following and seeing step 3 redirects to login.aspx without :445 appended to it...

`http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/wC5kW9Mbt/https://mail.itmanx.com:445/owa`

Internally I can access the site fine on `:443`

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Edit:
Done an iisreset before you ask :)

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to configure your web server to act as a reverse proxy for the /owa virtual directory rather than use a non-standard port.